# Separate a row to several row with unique id by get_json_object in hive

Tags: json, hive

I am trying to separate a row to several rows with unique question reference by get_json_object in Hive, Can I do it by this way?

I just touch get_json_object in Hive, trying to separate a row to several rows with unique question reference (which is from one json format column), and contain other column information.

```sql
SELECT  reference AS item_reference, 
        get_json_object(questions, '$.reference') AS question_reference,
        get_json_object(questions, '$.type') AS question_type
from sandbox.exportitems limit 10;
```

For example, given the input:

```
reference  | questions  
NP002_025  | [{"reference":"3dfc54c0","type":"clozeformula"}]
DP001_1_10 | [{"reference":"73879547","type":"imageclozeformula"},
              {"reference":"466a5b88","type":"clozedropdown"}]
```

The expected output is:

```
reference  | questions_reference | questions_type
NP002_025  | 3dfc54c0            | clozeformula  
DP001_1_10 | 73879547            | imageclozeformula  
DP001_1_10 | 466a5b88            | clozedropdown
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, as below is an example:

```
with core as (
SELECT 
    'DP001_1_10' as reference,
    explode(
        split(
            regexp_replace(
                regexp_replace(
                    regexp_replace('[{"reference":"73879547","type":"imageclozeformula"},{"reference":"466a5b88","type":"clozedropdown"}]', '\\]','')
                ,'\\}\\,\\{','\\}\\;\\{')
            ,'\\[','')
        ,'\\;')
    ) as json_str
)
select 
    reference,
    get_json_object(json_str,'$.reference') as questions_reference,
    get_json_object(json_str,'$.type') as questions_type
from 
    core;
+-------------+----------------------+--------------------+--+
|  reference  | questions_reference  |   questions_type   |
+-------------+----------------------+--------------------+--+
| DP001_1_10  | 73879547             | imageclozeformula  |
| DP001_1_10  | 466a5b88             | clozedropdown      |
+-------------+----------------------+--------------------+--+
```

You can just replace the example strings `'DP001_1_10'` and `'[{"reference":"73879547","type":"imageclozeformula"},{"reference":"466a5b88","type":"clozedropdown"}]'` to your column name of `reference` and `questions`.
So the final hql you want maybe like below:

```
with core as (
select 
    reference,
    explode(
        split(
            regexp_replace(
                regexp_replace(
                    regexp_replace(questions, '\\]','')
                ,'\\}\\,\\{','\\}\\;\\{')
            ,'\\[','')
        ,'\\;')
    ) as json_str
from
    sandbox.exportitems
)
select 
    reference,
    get_json_object(json_str,'$.reference') as questions_reference,
    get_json_object(json_str,'$.type') as questions_type
from 
    core;
```

Comment: Thanks! I solved it!           I got the error firstly:"SemanticException [Error 10081]: UDTF's are not supported outside the SELECT clause, nor nested in expressions".  Then I used "lateral view" before "explode".  This is the new query:

Comment: with core as (
select 
    reference,
    question_inf
from
    sandbox.exportitems
    lateral view explode(
        split(
            regexp_replace(
                regexp_replace(
                    regexp_replace(questions, '\\]','')
                ,'\\}\\,\\{','\\}\\;\\{')
            ,'\\[','')
        ,'\\;')
    ) adTable  as question_inf    
)
select 
    reference AS item_reference,
    get_json_object(question_inf,'$.reference') as questions_reference,
    get_json_object(question_inf,'$.type') as questions_type
from 
    core;